# change one field with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to change just one field before set the values with PHPExcel: 
For example to set `001` before the phone number:

```
....

if ($result = $DB->execute($sql) or die(mysql_error())) {
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List');
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $col = 'A';
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber, .'001 '.$row['phone']);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col . $rowNumber, $cell);
            $col++;
        }
        $rowNumber++;
    }
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myFile.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, here ? do you get an error ? does something "not work" *(if so, what result do you get ?)* ?

Comment: PS. Why is there a second setCellValue line that is overwriting the action of the first, and trying to store the cell object itself as the cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValueExplicit($col.$rowNumber, .'001 '.$row['phone'], PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

or set the number format mask to use the requisite number of digits, which will then give leading zeroes if the number is shorter